# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk - eb deploy fails on .NET core On Linux

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my application to elastic beanstalk via CLI on a **.NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/2.1.2** enviorment. But getting error.

By the way, this is a console application.

```
$eb deploy my-application-env
Creating application version archive "app-5c2f-210223_114601".
Uploading myapplication/app-5c2f-210223_114601.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2021-02-23 08:46:06    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2021-02-23 08:46:45    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2021-02-23 08:46:48    ERROR   Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.
2021-02-23 08:46:48    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-02-23 08:46:51    ERROR   [Instance: i-0791a0f52214a79a0] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2021-02-23 08:46:51    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-02-23 08:46:51    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0791a0f52214a79a0'. Aborting the operation.
2021-02-23 08:46:51    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

as you see, error is:

> Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.

But I'm sure that myapplication.runtimeconfig.json is placed in build directory.

Here is my myapplication.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Production.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    <None Include="appsettings.Test.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    <None Include="runtimeconfig.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
  <None Include="web.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have searched internet, there is some solutions about Visual Studio tools that can deploy, but I need to do this work via CLI because I'm trying to implement CI/CD.